# самый простой контроль версии в ubuntu 20

Tags: контроль-версий

Пытаюсь у*становить самую простую программу контроля версий с **интерфейсом графическим*** (аналог TortoiseHg).
Пытался установить monotone и rabbitvcs .
Не ставится .

Не знаю как быть.

Comment: Чем гит не зашел?

Comment: @handowl 1995 закончился ;_;

Comment: И чем вас не устраивает TortoiseHg?

Comment: А чем консоль не графический интерфейс? Но если что, к нему есть girl, gitg,  их тысячи  https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux

Comment: @AlexeyTen не смог установить ;_;

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо , а я искал почему-то мне поисковик не предложил такие игрушки

Comment: Гугл/Яндекс  знает, что Вы ищите и не будет предлагать то, что он думает Вам не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Установил смартГит](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download/)

[Установка простая](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download/#installation-instructions)

вот так :3
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]